# How to implement AutoCompleteExtender OnclientPopulated behaviour?

Tags: autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to implement an autocomplete list using the Ajax toolkit: AutoCompleteExtender

How to achieve the following behaviours using Ajax toolkit: AutoCompleteExtender?
Can provide any code examples also?

- Like google search, when the autocomplete list if display base on the inputs. When the mouse is move out or focus on other area. The autocomplete list is still showing base on the input value.
- If user enter abc and system display autocompletelist like abcd, abcde. When user move the mouse out and then click back the same input abc system should again display the autocomplete list.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer using jQuery UI Autocomplete.

Demo & Code:

[jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

**Sample JS Code:**

```
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }
    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P",
                    style: "full",
                    maxRows: 12,
                    name_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                            value: item.name
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
            "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first point is the ajax ACE (Auto Complete Extender) default behavior.

the second one, you can use jquery [.mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) and [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) event to shave your contextKey in a hidden field on mouse leave and fill it again in mouse enter.